# PHP- linebreak does not work

Tags: php

I found that linebreak solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726855/elegant-solution-for-line-breaks-php)

a) But the result of the echo has no linebreaks, what is wrong?

b) Can I do linebreaks in the echo as well?

PHP

```
<?php
$var = "Hi there\nWelcome to my website\n";
echo $var;
 ?>
```

Comment: "View source" and you'll see the line breaks in your browser... but browsers don't "render" line breaks, only `<br />`

Comment: check my code user2727841...

Comment: check one more link it is very useful!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linebreak `\n` works when you run your script in console where this code means line break. Depending on the OS it can be `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`. It will also work in web, in `<PRE>` block. Otherwise you must use `<br />` or call `nl2br()` function on your string to tell PHP to do that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Usually `\n` line breakings are used in CLI mode. I suppose you are using it through the web browser, so you can use HTML as it's primary used to control the view. `$var = "Hi there <br /> Welcome to my website <br />";`

Answer (score 3):

Use html break element `<br/>` to print line break. For detailed information look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Answer (score 3):

you have different ways to do it.

First...

```
$var = "Hi there <br /> Welcome to my website <br /> ";
echo $var;
```

Second is

```
$var = "Hi there \n Welcome to my website \n ";
echo nl2br($var);
```

And also third one

```
$var = "Hi there ".PHP_EOL." Welcome to my website".PHP_EOL;
echo nl2br($var);
```

**PHP_EOL** is php constant and its value is **\n**.

get the description of nl2br
http://pk1.php.net/nl2br

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp

And also see this it is very useful

http://www.go4expert.com/articles/difference-n-rn-t8021/

**Remember:** In file writing `<br>` doesn't work only `\n` will work `\n` means new line but if you are using html `<br>` tag is helpful.

Comment: The value of PHP_EOL is actually platform-dependent

Comment: Ok!!! I did't read. Can you give me link about this???

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mark Baker...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $var = "Hi there\nWelcome to my website\n";
  echo nl2br($var);
 ?>
```

Line breaks in HTML are not rendered by browsers, so you'll need a `<br/>`-tag. the `nl2br()` function will provide that for you in case your text doesn´t have it before.